# If I encounter a verb in the Duden, how can I tell which grammatical cases and prepositions to use with that verb?

Tags: verb, preposition, grammatical-case, duden

If I encounter a verb in the Duden, how can I tell which grammatical cases and prepositions to use with that verb?

For instance, I know the following verb usages are correct:

- Ich erreiche dich. (Use Accusative Case not Dative Case)
- Ich helfe dir. (Use Dative Case not Accusative Case)
- Ich warte auf den Bus. (Use *auf* not *für*)
- Ich fürchte mich vor Spinnen. (Use *vor* not *von*)

However, if I visit the Duden pages for [erreichen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erreichen), [helfen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/helfen), [warten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/warten) or [fürchten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuerchten) there isn't anything that particularly flags the above information. Is it possible to find this information in the Duden? Are there other common sources which contain this information?

Comment: DWDS is better about that: [erreichen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erreichen), [warten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/warten#1)

Comment: Duden also provides examples, to be found scrolling down to *Bedeutungen*.

Comment: dict.leo.org might be more useful to you.

Comment: When regional variations cause a different case to be used, the Duden shows it something like [this](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erbarmen). (E.g. *Du erbarmst mich* (Germany) vs *Du erbarmst mir* (Austria)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Duden

The Duden page provides examples for each meaning of a word, from which you can deduce the case:

> **3. mit jemandem, etwas in Verbindung treten**
>
> > **Beispiele**
> >
> > > - wie, wo kann ich Sie erreichen?
> > > - ich habe die Firma, das Büro nicht erreicht
> > > - durch den Film erreicht man viele Menschen

"Sie", "die Firma / das Büro" and "viele Menschen" are neither genitive nor dative. Thus, it must be accusative case. (Nominative case is no option for the object of a verb.)

This is not perfect for a language-learner at beginner level.

## Leo.org

Canoo.net (later canoonet.eu) had been an excellent resource for language information. Unfortunately it has been closed a few months ago. The new owner is not interested in maintaining the website and database. Some of its content moved to leo.org, a German-to-various-other-languages dictionary site associated with the university of Munich. Currently a huge wealth of information seems to have vanished - hopefully not for good!

In any case, the dictionary itself is a bit more useful than Duden. It doesn't explicitly name the case, but it shows the possible prepositions and associated cases. "jds." conveys genitive case (for example: "jds. Platz einnehmen" = "to take somebody's place"), "jdm." (= "jemandem") dative and "jdn." (= "jemanden") accusative.

- (jdn./etw.) erreichen (-> accusative)
- (jdm.) helfen (-> dative)
- (auf jdn./etw.) warten (-> accusative)
- sich (vor jdm./etw.) fürchten  (-> dative)

Answer (score 2):

The Duden may not be the best dictionary for you as it is targeted to native speakers. The answer, however, is to look at the examples.