# When to use a bare infinitive with machen?

Tags: infinitive

This is from a translation of C Dicken's A Christmas Carol, which can be found [here](http://paralleltext.io/read/?b=de-en-a-christmas-carol):

> Die Kälte in seinem Herzen machte seine alten Züge erstarren,

Why is this not,

> Die Kälte in seinem Herzen machte seine alten Züge **zu** erstarren,

and if I were to attempt to write something similar, what research could I do that would reveal to me that machen in this usage requires a bare infinitive?

Comment: Basically the same question [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60767/if-i-encounter-a-verb-in-the-duden-how-can-i-tell-which-grammatical-cases-and-p) (although that question only mentions *cases and prepositions*, the same situation holds for verbal complements).

Comment: I gather from the given link that one basically must look for existing examples. But I would like to know how that would be done. For instance, if I want to write the above sentence I would need to find sentences that included both machen and erstarren. How would I do that? I have tried both a Google search and a search in DWDS without success.

Comment: This seems to be a rather dated translation. It's so old that it sounds wrong to me. Nowadays you would say "Die Kälte in seinem Herzen ließ seine alten Züge erstarren".

Comment: The original: "The cold within him froze his old features, ..."

Comment: I couldn't find a specific reference, but the 'rule' not modal implies you must use *zu* seems to be false. For example: *Die Kinder gehen täglich schwimmen.* *Er sieht den Zug ankommen.* I don't know what the correct rule is and I couldn't find it on-line, but I take it that that's what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Note that this problem exists English too. Compare *It made me feel sorry* vs *I asked  him **to** come*.

Comment: Also see [this excellent answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50172/35111).

Comment: @David Vogt -- Many of the verbs listed in that answer are given [here](https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs.htm). Some are also listed [here](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/category/11-infinitives/). I thought this [Grammis entry](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/verbs/view/400774/20) was the most relevant. But I still haven't found any kind of general rule that covers everything; perhaps it's just random. Apparently *brauchen* is even more of a modal non-modal verb, see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brauchen).

Answer (score 1):

We recently had the question: [If I encounter a verb in the Duden, how can I tell which grammatical cases and prepositions to use with that verb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/60767/35111)

Although that question only talks about cases (i.e. nouns or nominals) and prepositions, one could just as well add verbs to it and the answer would remain the same: It simply has to be learned (i) whether a verb can be combined with another verb and (ii) what form the dependent verb takes.

German has three infinitives governed by verbs ([Statusrektion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rektion#Statusrektion)):

1. **einfacher Infinitiv**, bare infinitive: *gehen*
2. **zu-Infinitiv**, infinitive with *zu*: *zu gehen*
3. **Partizip II**, past participle: *gegangen*

Learners will encounter these bit by bit when they are taught [periphrastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphrasis) tenses, moods, and voices. To give an example for each:

1. bare infinitive with **modal verbs**:
   *ich/er/sie will, muss, kann … gehen*
2. infinitive with *zu* with **scheinen** and the **modal passive**:
   *die Strategie scheint zu funktionieren*, *die Regeln sind einzuhalten*
3. past participle in the **perfect** and **passive**:
   *sie hat gewartet, er ist gegangen*; *die Kinder werden abgeholt*

This is exactly the same pattern as with non-verbal objects, where the following contrasts have to be learned as well:

> Ich helfe **dir**. Ich unterstütze **dich**.
> Er fürchtet **mich**. Er fürchtet sich **vor mir**.

While the most important verbs governing infinitives, i.e. those used in expressing periphrastic tenses, moods, voices, are introduced in textbooks, learners will have to learn the rest by looking at examples in dictionaries. Let me give one example for each type of infinitive.

For *machen*, DWDS has under [7a](https://www.dwds.de/wb/machen#d-1-7-1):

> jmdn. **stutzen, frösteln, lachen, weinen, etw. vergessen** machen

For *brauchen*, under [1b](https://www.dwds.de/wb/brauchen#d-1-1-2):

> etw. nicht **zu tun** brauchen (= etw. nicht tun müssen)

For *kommen*, under [1e](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kommen#d-1-1-5):

> **gelaufen, gefahren, geritten** kommen

One important final point: Of the three infinitives mentioned above, infinitive with *zu* are special in that they and only they can appear in subordinate clauses (*Infinitivkonstruktionen*). Therefore, googling [Verben mit *zu*-Infinitiv](https://www.google.com/search?q=Verben+mit+zu-infinitiv) will get you lists of verbs that have **clauses** as complements, such as *versprechen* and *versuchen*. The examples above are different in that two verbs combine within a single clause.

Comment: None of the links provided make any reference to "erstarren", so the question remains, is there a systematic way to learn how to use a particular verb, with regard to the question of a bare infinitive, or is it just a matter of encountering its usage in the course of reading and acquiring the knowledge haphazardly in that way? BTW, Google translate does indicate an answer to this question, but as one is frequently reminded here, one should not rely on Google translate. So on what should one rely?

Comment: @user44591 To see why the particular word *erstarren* is irrelevant here, again compare verbal arguments to other types of arguments. The verb *helfen* requires a dative object; you can combine it with *ihr, ihm, ihnen, der Frau, dem Mann, den Leuten* or any other noun. It just needs to be a dative. The same goes for verbs governing other verbs: *machen*, in that particular meaning, requires a bare infinitive. *Erfassen, stutzen, frösteln* etc. all satisfy that condition.

Comment: @user44591 As to finding out what form of infinitive to use: Dictionaries are useful, as they will usually have an example that will show what type of infinitive the governing verb (in this case *machen*) requires; the dependent verb (*erstarrren* in your case) doesn't get a say. This is the same process you would follow for verbs for which you don't know what case they govern: *er folgte Petra*. *Petra* has no case marking, so it can be anything besides genitive. So one looks for an occurrence of *folgen* with a pronoun or article: *er folgte ihr*, therefore *folgen* governs the dative.

Comment: Instead of *erfassen* read *erstarren* at the end of the first comment.

Comment: OK. I think I am beginning to see an approach. So, when I enter "Ich mach es erfrieren" in Google Translate it responds with "I make it freeze to death." And when I enter "Ich mach es zu erfrieren" it responds with "I do it to freeze to death." So if I want to say, "I make it do something..." I use the bare infinitive, but if I want to say, "I do something to something..." then I use zu. But the original sentence does not seem to be one that can unambiguously clarified by this approach. With or without the "zu" it appears to say the same thing.

Comment: @user44591 That is not a reasonable approach. Machine translation will translate anything, even if it's not German – and *ich mache es zu erfrieren* isn't. (The algorithm interprets *zu erfrieren* as an adverbial clause in that case. Most native speakers would reject that interpretation.)